# Converting a method to Lambda expression

Tags: java, lambda

I have a List and want to turn the list into a String using Lambda. Here is the code example doing it in a conventional way:

```
List<Character> list; //list is already populated
String result="";
for(Character c : list){
    result += c.toString();
}
return result;
```

I am trying to do this using lambda as follow and of course, gives me a compiler error:

```
StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
String result = list.forEach(buf->append(c).toString());
```

What is the correct lambda expression? (new to lambda).

Thanks

Comment: `list.forEach(buf::append);` and then get the `buf.toString()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
String result = list.forEach(buf->append(c).toString());
```

The above snippet is attempting to call an `append` method unrelated to `buf`, which isn't what you want to do (especially because `forEach` does not return a `String`). Instead, you can use:

```
StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
list.forEach(buf::append);
String result = buf.toString();
```

If you were to use a lambda, then this is equivalent to:

```
StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
list.forEach(c -> buf.append(c));
String result = buf.toString();
```

---

However, I'd recommend streaming the `List`, and then collecting it to a `String` instead:

```
List<Character> list; //list is already populated
String result = list.stream().map(Character::toString).collect(Collectors.joining());
```

If you want to explicitly use a lambda instead of a method reference, then you can change `Character::toString` to `c -> c.toString()`.

Comment: Thank you Jacob G. Do you have any suggestion for good reference material to learn lamda?

Comment: @Anthony You're welcome. I recommend reading [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html).

Comment: Today, I came across this great lambda reference fortuitously: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java/lambda-expressions.html